# bot.get_channel() Not working in the Cogs

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

This is working perfectly without a COG, But in the COG It's not working and generating the following errors:
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class channelinfo(commands.Cog):
    #@commands.Cog.listener() [EVENT]
    #@commands.command() [COMMAND]
    def init(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def channelinfo(self,ctx,*,val:str = None):
        val = val.replace('<','')
        val = val.replace('>','')
        val = val.replace('#','')
        print(val)
        channel = await bot.get_channel(int(val))
```

Even the discord.User is not working in the COG.
Error: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'

```
    @commands.command()
    async def userinfo(self,ctx,user:discord.User = None):
        msg = ''
        for a in user.roles:
            msg+= a.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
channel = await self.bot.get_channel(int(val))
```

Comment: channel = await self.bot.get_channel(int(val))

AttributeError: 'channelinfo' object has no attribute 'bot'

Comment: Aight i see, you put init instead of __init__

Comment: __ init __ without the spaces

Comment: [`bot.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) is not a coroutine, `bot.fetch_channel(id)` is.